FastColoredTextBox C#
Я использую .Net 8. При добавлении элементов FastColoredTextBox, пишет: "следующие элементы управления были успешно добавлены на панель элементов, но не включены в активном конструкторе". Если посмотреть все элементы, то они светятся серым цветом.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Возможно контрол несовместим с текущей версией .NET, из какой библиотеки контрол, и какая у неё версия?

из FastColoredTextBox версия 2.15.0.0, .NET пробовал разные: 5,6,7,8

Это очень старый проект, он несовместим с 5,6,7,8, он для .NET Framework 4.x или даже 3.5 и ранее. Лучше поищите что-то поновее. Наверняка есть.

если можете, отправьте что-нибудь похожее на fast colored textbox
